# How to fix css grid for microsoft edge version above 17, still doesnt work even with prefix

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, css-grid

Css-grid doesnt work on edge, but on firefox,chrome,safari.... works perfectly

I have tried prefix the code: Here it is https://codepen.io/karolis-rusevicius/pen/aPxqbY

Maby I am not defining something ? Or that just Edge doesnt support one of the things I use. I understand that grid can be defined in meany ways. I am tired of microsoft

```
<main id="wrapper"><div class="element1 grid-box">1</div>
<div class="element2 grid-box">2</div>
<div class="element3 grid-box">3</div>
<div class="element7 grid-box">7</div>
<div class="element8 grid-box">8</div>
<div class="element9 grid-box">9</div>
<div class="element10 grid-box">10</div>
</main>
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
#wrapper {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: auto;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-rows: 25% 1rem 25% 1rem 25% 1rem 25% 1rem 59% 1rem 80%;
  grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25% 59% 80%;
  -ms-grid-columns: 25% 1rem 25% 1rem 25% 1rem 25%;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
      grid-template-areas:
    "box1 box2 box2 box3"
    "box1 box2 box2 box3"
    "box1 box2 box2 box7"
    "box1 box2 box2 box7"
    "box8 box8 box9 box9"
    "box10 box10 box10 box10"
    ;
    }
    }


#wrapper .element1 {
background-size: 390px;
background-color: #493C87;
grid-area: box1;
}
#wrapper .element2 {
background-size: 390px;
background-color: #493C87;
grid-area: box2;
}
#wrapper .element3 {
background-size: 390px;
background-color: #493C87;
grid-area: box3;
}
#wrapper .element4 {
background-size: 390px;
background-color: #493C87;
grid-area: box7;
}
#wrapper .element7 {
background-size: 390px;
background-color: #493C87;
grid-area: box7;
}
#wrapper .element8 {
background-size: 390px;
background-color: #493C87;
grid-area: box8;
}
#wrapper .element9 {
background-size: 390px;
background-color: #493C87;
grid-area: box9;
}
#wrapper .element10 {
background-size: 390px;
background-color: #493C87;
grid-area: box10;
}
```

would love to understand what I am missing to work on edge

Comment: Ok, I have learned smth. If I use <a href="" class="element2 grid-box">2</a> IT WOKRS for Microsoft Edge, but doesnt work on any other browser. I use <a href=""><div class="element2 grid-box"></div></a> It works on Chrome,Safari ect.. BUt doesnt work on Edge . :((((

Comment: I am using Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134 and here is my result with MS Edge https://i.postimg.cc/2jHpBRsH/22.gif Here is a testing result with Chrome https://i.postimg.cc/Ss6SpTRB/21.gif You can see that I got the similar result in both browser. Can you please tell us, What is not working in MS Edge? If it is an expected output than I suggest you to update your Windows 10 to get latest update for MS Edge may help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Anyways there is no longer problem left just added <a class="element9 grid-box">9</a>      <a>    anchor instead of a div and added in css  a {display:content} and it works for any browser

Comment: From your last comment, I can see that you had solve your issue. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and after 24 hrs mark it as an accepted answer for this question may help other community members in future for similar kind of questions. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no longer problem left, just added 9  anchor instead of a div and added in css a {display:content} and it works for any browser

Comment: This answer is unclear: What do I need to do to fix?